# How can i use created date in User object formula field?

Tags: formula, formula-field, user

I need to create a formula field on createddate  of user object to  parse the month and year from it .But this field is not visible in formula merge options.But this field is visible on reports ....How to get my formula done on created date??

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do this.  I can't find any documentation from Salesforce on this, but there's an existing answer on success.salesforce.com:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000grZdAAI

It isn't available in the workflow formula editor either, so it looks like your only option is a regular field and a trigger to update the value whenever a record is created/updated.

Answer (score -1):

1. MONTH(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) //for month
   2.YEAR(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) //for year
   3.DAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) //for day

Comment: I have no issues in formula  ...I have issue on created date field ...when i use that field in formula i get invalid field